# Can array have methods in Go?

Tags: go

I am learning Go and found this code:

```
// newTestBlockChain creates a blockchain without validation.
func newTestBlockChain(fake bool) *BlockChain {
        db, _ := ethdb.NewMemDatabase()
        gspec := &Genesis{
                Config:     params.TestChainConfig,
                Difficulty: big.NewInt(1),
        }
        gspec.MustCommit(db)
        engine := ethash.NewFullFaker()
        if !fake {
                engine = ethash.NewTester()
        }
        blockchain, err := NewBlockChain(db, gspec.Config, engine, vm.Config{})
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
    blockchain.SetValidator(bproc{})
        return blockchain
}
```

My question is:

`gspec` variable is created as an associative array of 2 values with key '**Config**' and key '**Difficulty**', that's clear.

But then I see this line:

```
gspec.MustCommit(db)
```

and I don't understand, where was the '**MustCommit()**' function  declared? Also, does an array in Go have methods? Weird stuff. Only class can have methods in my understanding of software development and here, I am seeing an array that has functions (methods). What is up with this code?

Comment: "Only class can have methods" -- Go doesn't have classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> gspec variable is created as an associative array of 2 values with key
>   'Config' and key 'Difficulty' , that's clear.

It is not clear. It is false. `Genesis` is a `struct`. `gspec` is a pointer to a `struct`. A `struct` is not an associative array. In Go, a `map` is an associative array.

You have:

```
gspec := &Genesis{
    Config:     params.TestChainConfig,
    Difficulty: big.NewInt(1),
}
```

Where

```
// Genesis specifies the header fields, state of a genesis block. It also defines hard
// fork switch-over blocks through the chain configuration.
type Genesis struct {
    Config     *params.ChainConfig `json:"config"`
    Nonce      uint64              `json:"nonce"`
    Timestamp  uint64              `json:"timestamp"`
    ExtraData  []byte              `json:"extraData"`
    GasLimit   uint64              `json:"gasLimit"   gencodec:"required"`
    Difficulty *big.Int            `json:"difficulty" gencodec:"required"`
    Mixhash    common.Hash         `json:"mixHash"`
    Coinbase   common.Address      `json:"coinbase"`
    Alloc      GenesisAlloc        `json:"alloc"      gencodec:"required"`

    // These fields are used for consensus tests. Please don't use them
    // in actual genesis blocks.
    Number     uint64      `json:"number"`
    GasUsed    uint64      `json:"gasUsed"`
    ParentHash common.Hash `json:"parentHash"`
}
```

https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core#Genesis

---

> [Composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)
>
> Composite literals construct values for structs, arrays, slices, and
>   maps and create a new value each time they are evaluated. They consist
>   of the type of the literal followed by a brace-bound list of elements.
>   Each element may optionally be preceded by a corresponding key.
>
> Taking the address of a composite literal generates a pointer to a
>   unique variable initialized with the literal's value.

```
gspec := &Genesis{
    Config:     params.TestChainConfig,
    Difficulty: big.NewInt(1),
}
```

`gspec` is constructed using a Go composite literal.

---

> [Method declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations)
>
> A method is a function with a receiver. A method declaration binds an
>   identifier, the method name, to a method, and associates the method
>   with the receiver's base type.
>
> The receiver is specified via an extra parameter section preceding the
>   method name. That parameter section must declare a single non-variadic
>   parameter, the receiver. Its type must be of the form T or *T
>   (possibly using parentheses) where T is a type name. The type denoted
>   by T is called the receiver base type; it must not be a pointer or
>   interface type and it must be defined in the same package as the
>   method.

A type of the form T or *T (possibly using parentheses), where T is a type name. may have methods; it must not be a pointer or interface type. A Go array type may have methods. A Go map (associative array) type may have methods. A Go struct type may have methods.

Go does not have classes.

---

References:

[The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is wrong. `gspec` isn't an associative array, but a object of type `Genesis`. The `Genesis` type is probably some sort of `struct`-type with various attributes and methods.

For examples on structs and methods you could visit the following [Go by Example](https://gobyexample.com) pages:

- [Structs](https://gobyexample.com/structs)
- [Methods](https://gobyexample.com/methods)

Comment: @AdamSmith: Your example is a slice, which is different from an array. [Array types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types) and [Slice types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types). See [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec).

Comment: *Every* type can have methods in go, even functions. Yes, you can declare a method on a method.

Comment: @MiloChristiansen: "**Every** type can have methods in go." Not **every** type. "it must not be a pointer or interface type and it must be defined in the same package as the method. [Method declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations)

Comment: True enough. Methods on interfaces would be kinda nonsensical, and there is a good reason why pointer types don't have them either, I just can't remember what it is... Oh well, if I really wanted to know I would look it up again :P. But for all practical purposes, if you want to add a method to a type, you probably can.